# T-SQL: how do you refer to database instance on this computer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

See screenshot; I am trying to select into a new table to be created in my QTYCompare database.

How do I refer to that in the 'into' statement?

It has a squiggly line under 'AFLOCAL' and when I try to run this, it tells me that

> The object name 'HOUKMISTRY1.AFLOCAL.QtyCompare.LegacyDataRaw' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

[image]

I am trying to select from a different connection that I have open that is on the network in a query window...

```
Select  
    Field9 as Product, 
    field25 as Suffix,
    field7 as HEAT,
    field10 as Quantity,
    field6 as AR_Numbers,
    field58 as Commodity
into 
    HOUKMISTRY.AFLOCAL.QtyCompare.LegacyDataRaw
from 
    ssFields 
where 
    ArchiveId = 16 
    and field6 is not Null 
    and (field6 not like '%,%')
```

Comment: You need to create a linked server, then use `[HOUKMISTRY1\AFLOCAL].QtyCompare.dbo.LegacyDataRaw`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create Link server with Read Write Access then you will be able to read or write data with that DB